# Programmatic transactional AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-transactions

I would like to set-up the following XML based transactional-AOP programmatically via Java:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor id="managerTx" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(* *..service.*Manager.*(..))" order="2"/>
</aop:config>
```

So far I have the following. I can create the expression pointcut like this:

```
   AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
   pointcut.setExpression("execution(* *..service.*Manager.*(..))");
```

Then perhaps using a combination of `AspectJPointcutAdvisor` and `AspectJAroundAdvice` I can set up the actual advice.

However, in looking at the Spring code that backs the `tx` namespace, it seems a `TransactionInterceptor` is created. Maybe I am looking at this all wrong.

Why do I want to do this, you ask?

Well I've moved my spring configuration from XML to @Configuration classes, but I'm stuck on how to translate the tx namespace stuff.  While, I am using `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@Transactional` annotations, it is too risky to add the annotation to all the methods matched by the pointcut expression described above. I am bound to miss something.

Answer (score 1):

In the other hand you are applying transaction to all methods that match. I do not recommend you to do this. Be very specific in the expression since even methods from third party libraries will have transaction. And also the granularity is poor with this approach. As I see you are adding the same properties.

Properties like readOnly are very important. A readOnly transaction does not    flushes and the end. Just an example.